# gvim custom command arguments

Tags: vim

I'm trying to create a custom command to use vimgrep to search a pattern in a given file pattern like

```
:command -nargs=* Find :tabnew <bar> vimgrep /<arg1>/gj <arg2> <bar> cw <cr>
```

How do I access the arguments arg1 and arg2?

**Edit 1**: I came up with the following solution

```
command! -nargs=* Find call VimFind(<f-args>)
function! VimFind(searchPattern,filePattern,...)
  let searchCommand = 'vimgrep /'.a:searchPattern.'/gj '.a:filePattern.'|cw'
  if a:0 > 0 && a:1 == 'n'
    let searchCommand = 'tabnew|'.l:searchCommand
  endif
  execute l:searchCommand
endfunction
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

**Edit 2**: Ah well, the above function errors out and then opens a new tab when nothing is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `<f-args>` and a function, Vim parses the individual command arguments for you; that's a correct way to do this.

To deal with errors from `:vimgrep`, you have to enclose the `execute l:searchCommand` with `try...catch`, e.g.:

```
try
    execute l:searchCommand
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E/
    tabclose

    echohl ErrorMsg
    echomsg 'Search failed'
    echohl None
endtry
```

I don't see why you need to `:tabnew` *before* the search; if you do this afterwards (but before the `:cw`), you don't have to clean up in case of failed searches.

Comment: Ah! I wanted to open the results in a new tab optionally based on a third parameter. Putting tab new between the vimgrep and cw works! how does this work? why does tabnew in the beginning give an error if vimgrep does not find anything?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the error comes from `:vimgrep`; however, the error message from inside a function is long and ugly, so the try..catch with `:echomsg` is better.